How to connect through SSL + Proxy after upgrading MongDB Java Driver to 5.2.0?
I am in the process of trying to upgrade from version 4.7.2 to 5.2.0 of the MongoDB Java Driver.
I used to deal with all SSH, SSL and Proxy configurations through a SocketFactory that I would pass to the mongo client like so:
MongoClientSettings.builder().streamFactoryFactory(
                (socketSettings, sslSettings) -> new SocketStreamFactory(socketSettings, sslSettings, socketFactory)
        );

This method was removed on version 5.0.0. It is not clear to me what the alternative now is to support this.
I read the documentation here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/upcoming/fundamentals/connection/
And here is a snippet of what I currently have:
InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();
mongoClientSettingsBuilder.applyToSocketSettings(builder ->
   builder.applyToProxySettings(proxyBuilder ->
      proxyBuilder.host(inetSocketAddress.getHostName())
         .port(inetSocketAddress.getPort())));

mongoClientSettingsBuilder.applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
   builder.context(context)
      .enabled(true)
      .invalidHostNameAllowed(connectionInfo.isSslInvalidHostNameAllowed());
 });

This half-works. I can connect through mongo servers with SSL, I can connect through a Proxy, but I cannot connect through a Proxy with SSL. It does reach the Proxy (I can see the traffic) but then the connection fails as it does not seem to have the required certificates:
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketWriteException): Exception sending message
|____/ SSL error: No valid certificate found
|_______/ Certificate error: No valid certificate found

How is this supposed to work?
